# Unable to copy to SnowFlake Database with Azure Data Factory

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, azure-data-factory

I have setup the ADF Link Service and Staging area to copy to SnowFlake Datawarehouse with Azure Data Factory. However, the actual copy activity returns the following error:

> ErrorCode=UserErrorOdbcOperationFailed,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=ERROR
> [22000] Cannot perform CREATE STAGE. This session does not have a
> current database. Call 'USE DATABASE', or use a qualified
> name.,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Runtime.GenericOdbcConnectors,''Type=System.Data.Odbc.OdbcException,Message=ERROR
> [22000] Cannot perform CREATE STAGE. This session does not have a
> current database. Call 'USE DATABASE', or use a qualified
> name.,Source=SnowflakeODBC_sb64.dll,'

The Sink settings are as followings

[image]

The dataset properties are as follows:

[image]

Any thoughts?

Comment: What are the SnowflakeTableDatset settings on Schema tab?

Comment: Does the testcomsnowflake already exists in snowflake database? And my guess is the linked service is already a successful connection but still wanted to confirm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Cannot perform CREATE STAGE. This session does not have a current database. Call 'USE DATABASE' or use a qualified name.

**This error often indicates that the database name is incorrect, that the database has not yet been established, or that the user does not have access to the database.**

**To resolve this, follow below steps:**

- Make sure while creating linked service you are connected to the correct database and the user you are using to login in it have appropriate permissions.
- You can use pre-copy script in snowflake connector to use that particular database with `use databasename` query.
  [image]

**And it is working fine for me:**
[image]

Comment: Once again, thank you@Pratik